# Setting up/Using Virtual router in OpenNebula

Tags: networking, router, opennebula, virtual-network

I am trying to install and use OpenNebula and so I am pretty new to this stuff. I have installed OpenNebula 4.4 having 1 frontend and 2 Worker nodes using the  [guide](http://docs.opennebula.org/4.4/design_and_installation/quick_starts/qs_ubuntu_kvm.html).

I can instantiate virtual machines and can SSH to them. For my network template I assigned leases using the IPs that were available in my Worker Node's network.

Now I want to create a virtual private network with a virtual router so that I can instantiate VMs which will then be part of the private network. I read the  [OpenNebula Virtual Router guide](http://docs.opennebula.org/4.4/administration/networking/router.html) but couldn't understand clearly how to use the Virtual Router template in my setup.
Can anyone suggest a good way to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

This is my context, try it...

```
CONTEXT=[ 

 DHCP="YES|NO",

  DNS="8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8",

  FORWARDING="10.0.0.2:80", 

NETWORK="YES",

  NTP_SERVER="10.0.0.1",

  PRIVNET="$NETWORK[TEMPLATE, NETWORK_ID=\"6\"]",

  PUBNET="$NETWORK[TEMPLATE, NETWORK_ID=\"5\"]",

  RADVD="YES|NO",

  SEARCH="local.domain",

  SSH_PUBLIC_KEY="ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA0vPKeWeptds11EvF5gj+l+1hBFt5XXeVpkZiXCq1iM91J7w730aw+T9wsLpx7pZB2Qdn7sDjAzZqs0VF6aKg/WDRaqOht1A/c/6VdOtVgFGerAxJw5MtBMaGRikg1O7gg4gCh3FqxEA0+nmK51J3YZBVkCc74g3YO2s0u2P4qBACTrIreXJOh4S+6dOTwLa744ZlWVgyt7WqnHDr/bL2w3j6zbAiCsDBH7RhFITJdz5WqyftbQtaZ+h1S9kvbOS2/zn/Y57N8u1BU/hHeDbxBfMxIrAmEzCDI++a7rooYvdNuwBM0eOD8i7f/JAzaz6rJDHAn4Lzbs57A+gG4bYDhQ== root@nebula",

  TARGET="hdb",

  TEMPLATE="$TEMPLATE" ]

CPU="1"

DISK=[
  IMAGE="Virtual Router",
  IMAGE_UNAME="otheradmin" ]

GRAPHICS=[
  LISTEN="0.0.0.0",
  TYPE="VNC" ]

HYPERVISOR="vmware"

LOGO="images/logos/linux.png"

MEMORY="512"

NIC=[

  NETWORK="6.x",

  NETWORK_UNAME="otheradmin" ]

NIC=[

  NETWORK="Private Network",

  NETWORK_UNAME="otheradmin" ]

SCHED_REQUIREMENTS="ID=\"5\""

SUNSTONE_CAPACITY_SELECT="YES"

SUNSTONE_NETWORK_SELECT="YES"
```